# other application window close event

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How to detect other applications ***window close*** event or notification in **cocoa**/carbon based application?

eg. if there are multiple windows in TextEdit application how to detect close event on particular window rather than whole application itself.

Answer (score 1):

> How to detect other applications window close event or notification in
>   cocoa/carbon based application?

The way to do that sort of thing is to use MacOS X's [accessibility model](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXModel/OSXAXmodel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078-CH208-TPXREF102). There's [a good example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXModel/OSXAXmodel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078-CH208-TPXREF108) in the documentation that'll give you an idea of the kinds of things you can do with accessibility -- getting notified of windows being opened or closed is certainly among its capabilities.

And by the way: it works with both Cocoa and Carbon apps.