# Another application window close

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

```
Similar to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422327/other-application-window-close-event
```

Is there a way other than `Accessibility Model` to monitor if another application window was closed (not terminated)? I can't require to have users turn on Accessibility mode in order for this to work. `NSWorkspace` Notifications will only tell you if the application was terminated.

Comment: I ended up using AppleScript to solve this issue